# Merge [dexie] and [dexiejs] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[dexie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dexie) and [dexiejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dexiejs) both refer to the exact same [Dexie.js library](https://dexie.org/). They should be merged together.

[dexie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dexie) tag description:

> Dexie.js is a minimalistic wrapper for IndexedDB

[dexiejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dexiejs) doesn't have a tag description, but glancing through all of the questions reveals that they are all about the same IndexedDB wrapper library.

Comment: Do you have any preference for the main (merge target) tag?

Comment: The pattern regarding these js libraries seems to be that `.js` is appended. Maybe merge the tags, then rename the remaining one to `[dexie.js]`?

Comment: I agree that the remaining one should be `[dexie.js]` since on their website, Dexie.js stylizes itself as `"Dexie.js"`

Comment: Dexie's merge-night runner?

Comment: @Samathingamajig It's a little unclear, actually, because the website itself has references to non-"js" uses of the term, e.g. "Dexie Cloud" and "Who uses Dexie?". I think [dexie] is clear enough, and certainly is in more popular use than [dexiejs].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a tough one. The library itself isn't consistent in its use of the name; dexie.js is used in some places, but dexie appears to be more frequent.

Yes, the library does style itself as dexie.js, but both the website [and the readme](https://github.com/dexie/Dexie.js) says "dexie" instead of "dexie.js" in several places. TylerH also has a point; [dexie] seems to be clear enough, and does attract more attention than [dexiejs]. FWIW, only 7 [dexiejs] questions didn't have [dexie].

I'll merge dexiejs into dexie for now. If there then is a consensus for renaming dexie to dexie.js as well, that's still an option that can be done in a couple clicks. In either case, we all seem to agree we don't want [dexiejs], regardless of what the final target is.